# PouchDb Local database size

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, pouchdb

We are developing an app in ionic3 which use PouchDB and CouchDB. We would like  to launch on mid February but we are worry if the database grow too much I make run out of memory in device.

To test we'd like to insert thousands records and check database size.. here we have the problem. We can't find out how get local db size. 
I was diving in PouchDB documentation and I only found how to get info about remote database size but not local. I think remote size needs not to be equal than local. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution, it is partial because it only works in android, chrome and firefox but not in ios and safari. I get used and available storage with this

```
 calculaEspacio(){
let nav: any = navigator;
nav.storage.estimate().then((obj)=>{ 
  this.usado=Math.round(((obj.usage/1048576)*100))/100;
  this.total = Math.round(((obj.quota/1048576)*100))/100;
})}
```

Anyone know equivalent for webkit?

Comment: You can always embed a chromium browser in your ionic application to avoid any problems related to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
npm install pouchdb pouchdb-size
```

//index.js

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-size'));

var db = new PouchDB('test');
db.installSizeWrapper();
db.info().then(function (resp) {
    //resp will contain disk_size
})
```

pouchdb-size https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-size

Build Status Dependency Status devDependency Status

Adds disk_size to info()'s output for your *down backed PouchDB's.

Tested with leveldown, sqldown, jsondown, locket and medeadown. When it can't determine the database size, it falls back to the default info() output.

Answer (score 0):

Full informations [here](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html)

If you're using Ionic 3, I guess you can use the SQLite Plugin to have unlimited data

Comment: Keep in mind that the SQLite plugin is said to offer lower performance.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, for this reason I don't use it. What I really worried is performance with too much data because with Pouch I readed that make querys to couchdb is not a good practice and I have all data in my app (in arrays) and I search with functions like array.filter. I'm worried about performance when I have an array with hundred items. For testing I want to know how database grow and look performance troubles.